# Log likelihood implementation in Delphi

Tags: r, delphi

I am trying to compute a Log Likelihood score for occurrence of pairs of words in text and am getting the same anomalous results in my Delphi implementation which I've derived from Java and Python sources found online.  Ted Dunning who published on this source in 1993 gives these results for one particular pair:

- K11 (AB, ie joint frequency) = 110,
- K12 (word A without B nearby) = 2442,
- K21 (B without A nearby) = 111
- K22 (number of words other than A or B in the text) = 29114

and gives the desired result as 270.72

Dunning also gives an implementation in R at
http://tdunning.blogspot.co.uk/2008/03/surprise-and-coincidence.html

> Computing the log-likelihood ratio score (also known as G2) is very
>   simple,   `LLR = 2 sum(k) (H(k) - H(rowSums(k)) - H(colSums(k)))`
>   where H is Shannon's entropy, computed as the sum of `(k_ij / sum(k)) log  (k_ij / sum(k))` . In R, this function is defined as
>   `H = function(k) {N = sum(k) ; return (sum(k/N * log(k/N + (k==0)))}`

but I do not know R and am unsure how to translate that to Pascal.

My translation attempts include these functions

```
function LnOK(x : integer): extended;
begin
  if x<=0 then Result :=0
  else Result := Ln(x);
end;

function Entropy2(a, b: Integer): extended;
begin
  Result := LnOK(a + b) - LnOK(a) - LnOK(b);
end;

function Entropy4(a, b, c, d: Integer): extended;
begin
  Result := LnOK(a + b + c + d) - LnOK(a) - LnOK(b) - LnOK(c) - LnOK(d);
end;

function Log_likelihood_from_Java(f1, f2, joint, total_tokens: Integer): 
  single;
var
  k11, k12, k21, k22: Integer;
  matrixEntropy, rowEntropy, colEntropy: extended;
begin
  k11 := joint;
  k12 := f2 - joint;
  k21 := f1 - joint;
  k22 := total_tokens - f1 - f2 + joint;
  rowEntropy := Entropy2(k11 + k12, k21 + k22);
  colEntropy := Entropy2(k11 + k21, k12 + k22);
  matrixEntropy := Entropy4(k11, k12, k21, k22);
  if (rowEntropy + colEntropy < matrixEntropy) then
    Result := 0.0 // round off error
  else
   Result := 2.0 * (rowEntropy + colEntropy - matrixEntropy);
end;
```

The above returns `7.9419` instead of the desired `270.72` when it's called like this:

```
Log_likelihood_from_Java(2552, 221, 110, 31777);
```

Grateful for help!

Comment: What's really weird is that your code bears no obvious relation to the R code to which you link.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan this seems to be a porting from Java https://github.com/apache/mahout/blob/master/math/src/main/java/org/apache/mahout/math/stats/LogLikelihood.java

Comment: @fantaghirocco It seems like the asker has picked a poor and unclear implementation because he understands Java and not R. But the algorithm in the R code is much clearer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've found the issue in the translation of the `LnOk` function which should be as follows:

```
function LnOK(x: Integer): Extended;
begin
  if x = 0 then
    Result := 0
  else
    Result := x * Ln(x);
end;
```

---

**Off topic**

As a side note if I'm allowed, just to improve the coding style, you might prefer to *overload* the `Entropy` functions instead of calling them with different names:

```
function Entropy(a, b: Integer): Extended; overload;
begin
  Result := LnOK(a + b) - LnOK(a) - LnOK(b);
end;

function Entropy(a, b, c, d: Integer): Extended; overload;
begin
  Result := LnOK(a + b + c + d) - LnOK(a) - LnOK(b) - LnOK(c) - LnOK(d);
end;
```

Comment: @MikeScott LnOK implies a protected implementation if Ln that handles out of domain cases in a particular way. But this function does not do that. Yes it picks out x=0, but it ignores x<0. Otherwise it returns `x*Ln(x)` and not `Ln(x)` as the name implies. You should treat the R source code as a better basis for writing your code. Your code is something of a mess.

Answer (score 4):

I can't make any sense of the code that you wrote which bears no obvious relationship to the R code to which you linked. I did not make any attempt to reconcile these differences.

Here's a literal translation of the R code. The algorithm is much simpler written this way as I am sure you will agree.

```
{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

uses
  SysUtils, Math;

type
  TVector2 = array [1..2] of Double;
  TMatrix2 = array [1..2] of TVector2;

function rowSums(const M: TMatrix2): TVector2;
begin
  Result[1] := M[1,1] + M[1,2];
  Result[2] := M[2,1] + M[2,2];
end;

function colSums(const M: TMatrix2): TVector2;
begin
  Result[1] := M[1,1] + M[2,1];
  Result[2] := M[1,2] + M[2,2];
end;

function H(const k: array of Double): Double;
var
  i: Integer;
  N, kOverN: Double;
begin
  N := Sum(k);
  Result := 0.0;
  for i := low(k) to high(k) do begin
    kOverN := k[i]/N;
    if kOverN>0.0 then begin
      Result := Result + kOverN*Ln(kOverN);
    end;
  end;
end;

function LLR(const M: TMatrix2): Double;
var
  k: array [1..4] of Double absolute M; // this is a little sneaky I admit
  rs, cs: TVector2;
begin
  rs := rowSums(M);
  cs := colSums(M);
  Result := 2.0*Sum(k)*(H(k) - H(rs) - H(cs));
end;

var
  M: TMatrix2;

begin
  M[1,1] := 110;
  M[1,2] := 2442;
  M[2,1] := 111;
  M[2,2] := 29114;
  Writeln(LLR(M));
end.
```

**Output**

```
 2.70721876936232E+0002
```